# Adding a camera view to an UIImageView via UImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have code like in my photo.h file:

```
@interface PhotoViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *photoView;
    UIButton *choosePhotoButton;
    UIButton *takePhotoButton;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photoView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *choosePhotoButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *takePhotoButton;

- (IBAction) selectPhoto:  (UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction) takePhoto:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

In the photo.m file I call:

```
- (void) addPhotoView
{
    // Now add the photoView
    _photoView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 65.0, [self screenWidth], [self screenHeight] - 154.0)];
    // _photoView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.allowsEditing = YES;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

   [self.view addSubview:_photoView];
}
```

How do I make my _photoView be the view from the camera?

Comment: I have a custom UI view which has a UIImageView in a box on it. That shows the camera feed and then a button on the page gets pressed to take the photo and save it.

Comment: means open camara only box.,,  not view ??

Comment: I want the camera feed in my uiimageview which is a square (CGRectMake(x,y, width, height) on my PhotoViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try This [Open Camara on subview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

i Hope usefull us